# Lowercasing each word in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to pandas and have a column in a pandas dataframe that contains strings (non-lowercase) that I want to convert to lowercase. The dataframe column is called:

```
df['labels']
```

and its elements are all lists (of strings):

```
0     ["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"]
1     ["Pig", "Fish", "Giraffe"]
....
```

I would like to lower case each string in the list, intuitively I tried this:

```
for element in input_data['labels']:
    for word in element:
        word.lower()
```

but on a `print(input_data["labels"]` nothing was lowercased.

Comment: Any reasons for storing them as lists? Does each of the lists always contain 3 elements only? If so, considering to store them separate columns if it makes sense?

Comment: strings are immutable so `word.lower()` does nothing but create a new string.

Comment: @JohnGalt each would not necessarily have 3 elements, I also have other reasons for wanting to keep them in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following would work but generally it's a bad idea to store lists as data IMO:

```
In [18]:

df['labels'] = df['labels'].apply(lambda x: [w.lower() for w in x])
df
Out[18]:
                 labels
0     [cat, dog, horse]
1  [pig, fish, giraffe]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give you want you want --

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Labels' : [["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"],
                               ["Pig", "Fish", "Giraffe"]]})

df['Labels'].apply(lambda x: [y.lower() for y in x])

0       [cat, dog, horse]
1    [pig, fish, giraffe]
Name: Labels, dtype: object
```

**But**, like mentioned in comments, do you need to store the data is this way?